# How to optimize the method code this.calculate inside the constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

Maybe someone can help me to optimize the this.calculate method. I think that it can be more tiny that what I have now.

The objective is: grab string incoming argument of calc.calculate method and get amount of it or difference (based on the sign standing between numbers). Count of numbers - 2.

My function, method and constructor are working fine, but I think it too weigheble for such simple task.

```js
function Calculator() {

  this.calculate = function(sum) {
    this.summ = 0;

    this.sumArr = sum.split(' '); // make array from string to clear from non-numbers values
    this.newSum = this.sumArr.filter(function(number) {
      return number > 0;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < this.sumArr.length; i++) { // based on the sign standing between numbers calculate it
      if (this.sumArr[i] == '+') {
        return this.summ = parseInt(this.newSum[0]) + parseInt(this.newSum[1]);
      } else if (this.sumArr[i] == '-') {
        return this.summ = parseInt(this.newSum[0]) - parseInt(this.newSum[1]);
      }
    }
  };
};

var calc = new Calculator;

console.log(calc.calculate("3 + 7")); // 10
console.log(calc.calculate("3 - 7")); // -4
```

Comment: Since you don't have an actual problem that needs to be fixed I would suggest posting over at the code review stack exchange https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndrewLohr thank you )